# Space between tableview cells in TVos

Tags: tableview, tvos, uitableview

How to remove the default space between tableview cells in tvos? By
default its taking 14px gap between the tableview cell in tvos,but i
need to increase the space by 20px.

Answer (score 6):

The tableview adds that space for the focus animation, use a collectionview instead since it doesn't have a focus animation. You'll have to add the animation yourself though.